# While loop nested inside for loop only executes for first iteration of for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am having a problem with a while loop that is nested inside a for loop. It is executing perfectly on the first iteration of the for loop, but the for loop then skips over the while loop on all the other iterations.

I am trying to fill a list, nsteps_list, with the number of times the while loop executes, nsteps, for every iteration of the for loop. An expected answer would be something like List = [17, 16, 16, 14, 15, 13, 12, 15...], but all that is happening is List = [17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...]

Loop code here:

```
# Bisection Method

minn = np.arange(.00001, .001, 0.00005)
nsteps_list = [0.0] * (len(minn))  # Rewrite each index with nsteps as iterating through
nsteps = 0

for i in range(0, len(minn) - 1):

    while math.fabs(fx_2) > minn[i]:

        if fx_2 > 0:
            x_3 = x_2
            print "UPDATE: x_3 = " + str(x_2)

        elif fx_2 < 0:
            x_1 = x_2
            print "UPDATE: x_1 = " + str(x_2)

        x_2 = 0.5 * (x_1 + x_3)
        fx_2 = func(x_2)
        nsteps += 1

    print nsteps
    nsteps_list[i] = nsteps
    nsteps = 0

print "List: " + str(nsteps_list)
```

I know from experimenting that it iterates through the for loop fine, but it fails to go back into the while loop, and so the reset of nsteps to 0 is never changed, and my list is filled with 0's.

Here is the full code, in context:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import math


# Parabola = 3x^2-9x+2 ==> Has minimum and 2 real roots

def func(n):  # Defining function to get f(x) for each x for parabola

    a = 3
    b = -9
    c = 2

    fx = a * n * n + b * n + c
    return fx


# Calling parabola function on values in x
x = np.arange(-2.0, 4.0, 0.2)
y = func(x)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, x * 0)

# Declare Variables for bisection method

x_1 = 2.0
x_3 = 3.0
x_2 = 0.5 * (x_1 + x_3)

fx_1 = func(x_1)
fx_2 = func(x_2)
fx_3 = func(x_3)

if fx_1 >= 0:
    print "Warning: Variable x_1 not initialised correctly."
if fx_3 <= 0:
    print "Warning: Variable x_3 not initialised correctly."

# Bisection Method

minn = np.arange(.00001, .001, 0.00005)
nsteps_list = [0.0] * (len(minn))  # Rewrite each index with nsteps as iterating through
nsteps = 0

for i in range(0, len(minn) - 1):

    while math.fabs(fx_2) > minn[i]:

        if fx_2 > 0:
            x_3 = x_2
            print "UPDATE: x_3 = " + str(x_2)

        elif fx_2 < 0:
            x_1 = x_2
            print "UPDATE: x_1 = " + str(x_2)

        x_2 = 0.5 * (x_1 + x_3)
        fx_2 = func(x_2)
        nsteps += 1

    print nsteps
    nsteps_list[i] = nsteps
    nsteps = 0

print "List: " + str(nsteps_list)

print "x_2 = " + str(x_2) + " and f(x_2) = " + str(fx_2) + "."

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(np.log10(minn), nsteps_list)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x_2, fx_2, "mo")

plt.show()
```

So I need this array to plot on a graph against the log of the corresponding minn values. Any thoughts on what's wrong?

Comment: short answer:  because `math.fabs(fx_2) > minn[i]` is not true after the first iteration.

Comment: I think a lot of the initialization (e. g. `x_3 = 3` etc.) must take place _within_ the for loop, right before the while loop, so that in each iteration of the for loop the starting situation is re-instated.  But maybe I misunderstood the concept of the program.  Without detailed explanation what this shall accomplish, it's hard to guess.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I missed. Working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged your program. 
After the first `for` loop interation, the while loop runs 17 times.
`i` gets incremented from 0 to 1, and tries to evaluate the while-loop again.

at this pointvalue of `fx_2` here is `-8.63145396579057e-06`
and `minn[1]` is `6.0000000000000002e-05`

so the absolute value of `fx_2` is **less than** `min[i]` where `i==1`, thus not allowing the inner loop to be entered again, spitting out zeros for `nsteps` instead.

As I am not a math wiz, I suggest you take another look at what you're trying to compute.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying. I ended up figuring it out myself, and it was such a obvious detail! I wasn't resetting both of my x_1 and x_3 values. Adding that within the for loop has fixed my bug. Thanks for taking time to reply